# Continue while from nested for-loop

Tags: loops, powershell

I have the following loop structure:

```
while ($reader.Read() -eq $true)
{
    $row = @{}
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++)
    {
        if(something...)
        {
            #continue with while
        }
    }
    #do more stuff...          
}
```

Now, is there any way to continue from within the `for` loop with the next iteration of the outer `while` loop without any break-variable? So if "something is true" I do not want to go `#do more stuff` but instead do the next `$reader.read()`. `Continue` only goes to the next iteration of the `for` loop. `Break` will only break the `for` loop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Factoring out the inner loop to a function could improve readability, depending on how tangled up your variables are.

```cs
function processRow($reader) {
    $row = @{}
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++)
    {
        if(-not something...) { return $null }
        # process row
    }
    $row
}

while ($reader.Read()) {
    $row = processRow $reader
    if ($row) {
        #do more stuff...          
    }
}
```

But if you want to do this directly, you can, because PowerShell has labeled breaks:

```cs
:nextRow while ($reader.Read()) {
    $row = @{}
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++) {
        if(something...) {
            #continue with while
            continue nextRow
        }
    }
    #do more stuff...          
}
```

Comment: Thanks, those labled breaks seem to do the trick - though it feels somewhat like good old GOTO :)

Comment: Labeled breaks are what Donald Knuth would call a "structured `GOTO`" -- you cannot transfer execution to arbitrary places, only to well-defined ones (namely the ends of loops). To reinforce that, PowerShell doesn't even have a `GOTO` statement, which is fairly rare for a scripting language.

Comment: Just a small edit: It's `continue nextRow` not break :nextRow

Comment: You're absolutely right -- `break :nextRow` will terminate the outer loop from inside the `for`, which is not what we want (in this case, but it's also useful).

Comment: for me `continue nextRow` only works without the `:` With the : it will continue the for-loop

Comment: I was going by [the documentation on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847873.aspx), but when I consult the actual help in PowerShell, sure enough, the colon is omitted.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: a revised, recursive (and untested!) solution so your millage may vary:

```powershell
function doReader()
{
    while ($reader.Read() -eq $true)
    {
        $row = @{}
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++)
        {
            if(something...)
            {
                #continue with while
                doReader
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
doReader
#do more stuff
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant with "extra break-variable". I am currently using this but was looking for a nicer way ;)

Comment: @silent, give the edited answer a shot. Recursion is certainly more elegant

Comment: I wouldn't use recursion in a scripting language, because I wouldn't expect my future maintainer to understand it -- and I say this with all fondness for my future maintainers.